# Windows Defender (on Win 10) breaking System Restore

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender, system-restore

When I do a system restore in Windows 10 1607 (Anniversary Update), I get this error:
[image]

Based on the error, it looks like Windows Defender isn't playing well with System restore -- and lo and behold, when I disable Windows Defender, the System Restore works!

However, I don't have the option to remove Windows Defender -- the clients don't want that.

This is not an uncommon problem, and there are a few solutions out there.

Here's what I've tried:

(1)

The error says "System Restore could not access a file."  Maybe the problem is that a file is corrupted?  Windows Defender touches every file (I think), and maybe when it touches the corrupted file, it passes out like a scared goat.

So I ran the utility "System File Checker", but it didn't find any corrupted files.  Can I trust the utility?

(2)

Success with this problem was found by turning off something called *App & Browser control*.  The problem here is that I can't do that, because that's in the *Defender Security Center*, which isn't on the Anniversary Update (1607), it's on the Creator's Update (1709).

It seems that Windows Defender isn't near as configurable in 1607 than in 1709, and clients *also* don't want to update to 1709.  OUCH.  Am I missing a Windows Defender configuration that allows System Restore in 1607?  I see that you can get it to not touch certain files or folders, but I don't know what file/folder System Restore would be in, as it's not really a file.

(3)

Write a script that temporarily disables Windows Defender.  I actually haven't tried this because I'm not sure where to start.  I would insert the script into my program, which is in C#.  It would go like this:

- turn off Windows Defender
- run the code that does the restore point, and after it's done and the machine is restarted,
- turn Windows Defender back on.

After all that, here are some specific questions:

(1) how to write a script that toggles Windows Defender

(2) is there a way to configure Windows Defender in 1607 such that it allows System Restore to work?

(3) any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: To close voter: Based on the title alone I had the same thought, but if you read the entire question you'll find that it really is a programming question.

Comment: The question has elements of programming and elements of... messing with Windows.  Why would someone want to close the question?  I don't understand.